How to define dynamic domains in sendgrid?
I have two domains configured and added them to sendgrid

teste1.com.br
teste2.com.br

I can somehow define dynamic domains
when sending the email? for example, when an email is sent from the domain 'teste1.com.br' I want the "sent by" field in gmail to show the sender domain 'teste1.com.br'
And when an email is sent by 'teste2.com.br' I want the "sent by" field to appear as 'teste2.com.br', is it possible to configure this in sendgrid?
I created logic in my application to change the default domain via api, but sendgrid seems to have a delay in this change that ends up not serving very well
enter image description here
I've been researching how to link an api key to a domain, or how to dynamically change the domain but I got zero results, nothing satisfactory.
I had to build a function to change domains all the time
Is there something that makes a connection between the domain and the api key? or something I can set to send domains dynamically?
